# Bootstrap with ASP.net not using full screen

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can anyone point out why my navbar (I have more stuff but same problem) is not fully using my screen when in full screen? Not sure If i need to use class col but from other examples I do not see people having to use this for their nav bar. Not sure if it has something to do with the asp form or not. 
First time using bootstrap.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A72q7.jpg)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="admin.aspx.cs" Inherits="SCBA.admin" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Admin</title>
        <link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="stylesheet3.css"  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div class ="container-fluid">
                     <div class="navbar-header">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnadministration" runat="server" cssClass="button1" onclick="btnadministration_Click" Text="Administration" /> 
                             <br>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnresource" runat="server" cssClass="button1" onclick="btnresource_Click" Text="Resource" />  
                     </div>
                     <div class="navbar-right">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnlogout" runat="server" cssClass="button1" onclick="btnlogout_Click" Text="Logout" />  
                     </div>  
                     <div class="header1">Tracking System</div>
                     <div class="header2">Admin View-Super Admin</div>  
                      </div>                          
                 </div> 
             </div>      
      </form>
        <script src="../Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../Scripts/boostrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use class **container-fluid** instead of **container** in the first div

**container** has a fixed width which is used in larger screen but **container-fluid** has no fixed width, so it takes the full width of the body

Comment: "Container" has an attribute max-width.